# magento how to show attribute image on list view

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-view

I already loaded few custom attributes on the product list view. Now I want to show images instead of the attribute values.

I tried:

```
$filename= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/media/catalog/brands/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'.jpg';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
      echo '<img style="float: left; margin: 2px;" src="/media/catalog/brands/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'.jpg" alt="'.$brand.'">'; 
  }
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand. The product images are already being displayed in the category.

See: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

Comment: I want to load attribute icon as not image , here is the example how i cons should look http://snag.gy/5zTfP.jpg , i don,t want to replace product image with attribute image

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show custom attribute image if available

You need to code like below

```
    <?php 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$brand = $product->getData('attribute-code-here'); 
$filename = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/brands/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'.jpg';

    if(@getimagesize($filename)){ ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $filename; ?>" alt="" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I want to load attribute icon as not image , here is the example how i cons should look snag.gy/5zTfP.jpg , i don,t want to replace product image with attribute image

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Mage::getBaseDir('media')
```

instead of

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/media'
```

and in the image src attribute

```
Mage::getBaseUrl('media')
```

instead of

```
/media
```

If it still does not work, and `$brand` actually contains the attribute value, then the images are obviously not in the place where you are looking for them.